# Unable to get app icons using device_apps plugin

Tags: flutter

Guys I am trying to get the app icon of other apps in my flutter app using Device_apps plugin and I am unable to get the icons.

```
Future<List<Widget>> getApps() async {
    List<Widget> totalApps = [];
    List<Application> apps = await DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications(
        onlyAppsWithLaunchIntent: true, includeSystemApps: true);
    apps.forEach((element) {
      Application app = element;
      if (app is ApplicationWithIcon)
        print('app icon is there');
      else
        print('app icon is not found');
      ListTile object = ListTile(
        leading: app is ApplicationWithIcon
            ? CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: MemoryImage(app.icon),
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              )
            : null,
        title: Text('${element.appName}'),
      );
      setState(() {
        totalApps.add(object);
      });
    });
    return totalApps;
  }
```

when I use this I get the following output iterated many times

```
I/flutter ( 8716): app icon is not found
```

could you please help me out with this problem. And if possible please suggest me other plugins which provide the same feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change

```
 List<Application> apps = await DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications(
        onlyAppsWithLaunchIntent: true, includeSystemApps: true);
```

to

```
await DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications( includeAppIcons: true, includeSystemApps: true, onlyAppsWithLaunchIntent: true)
```

then it worked perfectly